# SignalR (Azure) drops web socket connection every 15 min

Tags: signalr, signalr.client, azure-signalr

We have SPA (on Angular) with ASP.NET Core at the backend. We are leveraging Azure SignalR for communication.

**Problem:** SignalR client side drops WebSocket connection every 15 mins. That's confirmed by Network tab as well as Azure SignalR service logs.

It sound like it is either SignalR client library has some timeouts or maybe WebSockets themselves.

**Tested:** on different environments (different Azure SignalR service), on different browsers (Chrome, Firefox), on different browser locations (behind different networks), with different ASP.NET app hosting options (on IIS, on IIS Express, on Azure App Services). The result is always the same: WebSocket connection lasts exactly 15 mins.

**One interesting fact:** it is failing not only with specific interval, but also at specific times: at 0th, 15th, 30th, 45th min of every hour.

Guess this can be fixed with some configuration, but default "KeepAlive and other timeouts" look good.

[Browser logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CjcP.png)

[Azure SignalR logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzBeD.png)